# Converting Columns Into Rows Using Pivot In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

**I have the following table as Follows:**

[image]

I Would like to Convert it as Follows:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Child_Code |     SewingStart     |      SewingEnd      |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     000001 | 2017-02-21 00:00:00 | 2017-03-21 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Any Help Please!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Add some more sample data to make things trickier and more describing. (If it always is two dates per code, you can do a group by.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a limited number of rows, you can use conditional aggregation or pivot.  But, you need a column for this.  So:

```
select child_code,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then plan_date end) as plan_date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then plan_date end) as plan_date_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by child_code order by plan_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by child_code;
```

You can only use this method if you know the maximum number of plan dates that you want.  Otherwise, you will need to use a dynamic pivot.  The idea is the same, but the query string needs to be constructed and should then be passed to `sp_executesql`.

EDIT:

If you have only two values, then `group by` is probably easier.  The following handles the case where there is only one value:

```
select child_code, min(plan_date) as plan_date_1,
       (case when min(plan_date) <> max(plan_date) then max(plan_date)
        end) as plan_date_2
from t
group by child_code;
```

Comment: Wow!! It Works!! No Problem! plan_date is restricted to two!! Dear Gordon Linoff, I need some more help from you!! wait  I shall mention you here..Hope You will Help me

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic sql if the maximum number of `plan_date` is unknown. You will need to use [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to number each list partitioned by `Child_Code` for use with [**`pivot()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

test setup:

```
create table t (child_code varchar(6), plan_date datetime);
insert into t values ('000001','20170221'),('000001','20170321');
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ',' + quotename('Plan_Date_'
          +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by Child_Code 
              order by     Plan_Date 
          ))
          )
      from t 
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'');

select @sql = '
 select Child_Code, ' + @cols + '
 from  (
  select 
      Child_Code
    , Plan_Date
    , rn=''Plan_Date_''+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
          partition by Child_Code 
          order by     Plan_Date 
        ))
  from t
    ) as a
 pivot (max([Plan_Date]) for [rn] in (' + @cols + ') ) p';
 select @sql as CodeGenerated;
 exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/YQCR87525

code generated:

```
 select Child_Code, [Plan_Date_1],[Plan_Date_2]
 from  (
  select 
      Child_Code
    , Plan_Date
    , rn='Plan_Date_'+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
          partition by Child_Code 
          order by     Plan_Date 
        ))
  from t
    ) as a
 pivot (max([Plan_Date]) for [rn] in ([Plan_Date_1],[Plan_Date_2]) ) p
```

returns

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Child_Code |     Plan_Date_1     |     Plan_Date_2     |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     000001 | 21.02.2017 00:00:00 | 21.03.2017 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! It also Works for me!!

Comment: Please See my Question Again..I have modified it some extend as I have replace Plan_Date_1 with SewingStart and Plan_Date_2 With SewingEnd!!